# How do you create a two column table, where the columns are separate?

Tags: tables, sectioning, packages

I would like to create a two-column table, but want the two columns to be separate (so multicols doesn't work), to model a balance sheet in accounting. I would like it to look like this, any packages that can help, or tips?[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The simplest would be to load the ` array` package (if not already done) and add, between the two column specifiers `!{\qquad}` or `!{\hskip some length}`. For the horizontal lines, you can use `\cmidrule` from `booktabs`  which can be cropped at each extremity (independently).

Comment: You could do this with tabulars (that is, tabulars inside tabulars).  The only tricky bit would be aligning the last line.

Comment: You can  add a narrow empty columns as `p{1ex}` or with booktabs, instead of use some like `\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{2-2}` that will look like a single `\hline`, type  `\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-2}` to add a small break between both lines. Note that this is done  shorting the lines, not adding a space between.